# mm vcard - contact card looks bad

Tags: sms, vcf-vcard, mms, plivo

I'm sending an mms with contact card (vcard)
through Plivo API.

But the contact card looks bad on the device.

I used several headers variations but still looks bad.

attached bad version and how it should look.

** plivo API body:

```
{
    "dst": "+11111111",
    "src": "+1111111",
    "text": "Hello, this is test mms vcard 6",
    "type": "mms",
    "media_urls": [
        "https://vcardurl.com/vcard/asdadsdaa"
    ]
}
```

these are the headers I'm sending with the file:

```
const contentHeader = 'text/x-vcard; name="card.vcard"';
const contentDisposition = 'inline; filename="card.vcard"';

const responsea = new Response(vcardStra, {status: 200, headers: {
    'Content-type': contentHeader,
    'Content-Disposition': contentDisposition
}})
```

different variations I tried, file name extension and the header:

```
.vcf text/vcard
.vcf text/v-card  (Plivo failed to send)
.vcf text/x-vcard (Plivo failed to send)

.vcard  text/vcard
.vcard  text/v-card (Plivo failed to send)
.vcard  text/x-vcard
```

[image: good versio]

[image: bad version]

Answer (score 0):

Mohammed Huzaif here; I'm a developer evangelist for Plivo. This, in my opinion, is more of an operator problem or sometimes framework may cause issue too. To see how things work, I advise trying [vcard-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vcards-js)'s recent version. In case you continue to have issues, I suggest contacting our [support team](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us).